# keyNotFoundError while Fetching JSON data from an API in SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift

I recently started learning to code in Swift and I have been struggling to fetch data from an API. This is what the data looks like:

```
{
   "status":200,
   "posts":[
      {
         "text":"djnkdnwnjdewkn",
         "date":"08/07/2012"
      },
      {
         "text":"dskndkc ksdskj n",
         "date":"08/17/2012"
      },
      {
         "text":"dkjdjincidjn",
         "date":"09/07/2012"
      }
   ]
}
```

And here is the code I have used:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
    public var id = UUID()
    public var text, date: String
}

struct Feed: Codable {
    public var status: Int
    public var posts: [Post]
}


class FetchPosts: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [Post]()

    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "api goes here")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let postData = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Feed.self, from: postData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.posts = decodedData.posts
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}


struct FeedView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchPosts()
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack {
                ForEach(fetch.posts) { post in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(post.text)
                        Text("\(post.date)")
                            .font(.system(size: 11))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to generate any output so far but I have been getting an error:

> "keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "posts", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil) ("id").", underlyingError: nil))"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Add `CodingKeys`

```
struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
    public var id = UUID()
    public var text, date: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { // add this for keys to be decoded 
       case text, date 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If not all properties of your struct are part of the json you need to define a CodingKey enum to the struct and list the properties that is included in the json

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case text, data
}
```